# How does this hybrid flexbox/grid layout SCSS mixin work?

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, grid-layout

I found a SCSS mixin for a flexbox/grid layout [HERE](https://github.com/W3cplus/SassMagic/blob/master/src/mixins/_flex-grid.scss).

Here is the full mixin:

```css
@mixin grid-col(
        $col: null,
        $grid-columns: 12,
        $col-offset: null,
        $gutter: null,
        $condensed: false,
        $align-self: null,
        $flex-grow: 0,
        $flex-shrink:1,
        $flex-basis: auto,
        $order: null,
        $grid-type: skeleton,
        $last-child: false
    ){

    @if type-of($col) == number and unitless($col) == true {
        $flex-grow: 0;
        $flex-shrink: 0;
        $flex-basis: percentage($col / $grid-columns);

        @if $grid-type == skeleton {
            @if $gutter and unit($gutter) == '%' {
                $flex-basis: $flex-basis - $gutter;
            } @else if $gutter and unitless($gutter) == false {
                $flex-basis: calc(#{$flex-basis} - #{$gutter});
            }
        } @else if $grid-type == margin-offset {
            @if $gutter and unit($gutter) == '%' {
                $flex-basis: (100% - ($gutter * ($grid-columns / $col - 1))) / ($grid-columns / $col);
            } @else if $gutter and unitless($gutter) == false {
                $flex-basis: calc( #{$flex-basis} - #{$gutter * ($grid-columns / $col - 1) / ($grid-columns / $col)} );
            }
        }

        @if $col-offset and unit($col-offset) == '%' {
            $flex-basis: $flex-basis + $col-offset;
        } @else if $col-offset and unitless($col-offset) == false {
            $flex-basis: calc( #{$flex-basis} + #{$col-offset} );
        }
    } @else if type-of($col) == number and unitless($col) == false {
        $flex-grow: 0;
        $flex-shrink: 0;
        $flex-basis: $col;
    } @else if type-of($col) == string and $col == 'auto' {
        $flex-grow: 1;
        $flex-shrink: 1;
        $flex-basis: auto;
        max-width: 100%;
        width: auto;
    } @else if type-of($col) == string and $col == 'equal' {
        // flex: 1
        $flex-grow: 1;
        $flex-shrink: 1;
        $flex-basis: 0;
    } @else if type-of($col) == string and $col == 'none' {
        // flex: none
        $flex-grow: 0;
        $flex-shrink: 0;
        $flex-basis: auto;
    } @else if type-of($col) == string and $col == 'initial' {
        // flex: initial
        $flex-grow: 0;
        $flex-shrink: 1;
        $flex-basis: auto;
    } @else if type-of($col) == string and $col == 'breakpoint' {
        $flex-grow: 0;
        $flex-shrink: 1;
        $flex-basis: auto;
        width: 100%;
    }

    flex: $flex-grow $flex-shrink $flex-basis;

    @if $align-self {
        align-self: $align-self;
    }

    @if type-of($order) == number {
        order: $order;
    }

    @if $gutter and unitless($gutter) == false {
        @if $grid-type == skeleton {
            @if $condensed == true {
                @include grid-gutter($margin: 0 $gutter / 2);
            } @else {
                @include grid-gutter($margin: 0 $gutter / 2 $gutter);
            }
        } @else if $grid-type == margin-offset {
            @if type-of($col) == string and $col == 'breakpoint' {
                @include grid-gutter($margin-right: 0);
            } @else if $last-child {
                @include grid-gutter($margin-right: 0);
            } @else {
                @include grid-gutter($margin-right: $gutter);
            }

            @if $condensed == false {
                @include grid-gutter($margin-bottom: $gutter);
            }
        }
    }

    @content;
}
```

I don't understand what all the parameters in this mixin are meant to do, e.g. `$condensed: false,`. I have worked with flexbox and Scss quite a bit, but I just find this mixin to be a bit beyond me.

Specifically, I'm struggling to understand this part of the mixin:

```css
@else if $grid-type == margin-offset {
    @if $gutter and unit($gutter) == '%' {
        $flex-basis: (100% - ($gutter * ($grid-columns / $col - 1))) / ($grid-columns / $col);
    } @else if $gutter and unitless($gutter) == false {
        $flex-basis: calc( #{$flex-basis} - #{$gutter * ($grid-columns / $col - 1) / ($grid-columns / $col)} );
    }
}
```

Can somebody explain this part to me?

Comment: @LGSon this question is a _very_ poor fit over there - it would be quickly voted down and closed, see [Why are implementation and debugging questions off-topic on Software Engineering?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7864/31260) Recommended reading: **[What goes on Software Engineering (previously known as Programmers)? A guide for Stack Overflow](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat Okay, but I already changed from _Software Engineering_ to _Code Review_....? IYO, is that a good place?, or what would you suggest?

Comment: hardly so @LGSon - see "six-yes" requirement in [their help center](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), it doesn't look like this one is met: "To the best of my knowledge, does the code work as intended?"

Comment: @gnat Of course it is met "To the best of **my knowledge**, does the code work as intended?"

Comment: Who on Earth closed this as belong on Super User?

Comment: @AlexanderSolonik What don't you understand about that mixin? The properties? The equations?

Comment: @TylerH Thanks , i know how mixins work , what i did not understand is a practical usage of this mixin , however this is not a debugging question as this is a grid layout mixin that is part of a larger framework and i taught the problem was global enough for me to ask it on stackoverflo.

Answer (score 1):

This is the header of your file:

> // ===================================================================
>   // Flexbox Grid Mixins
>   // Version 0.1.3
>   // Description: Sass Mixins to generate Flexbox grid
>   // Author: thingsym
>   // GitHub: https://github.com/thingsym/flexbox-grid-mixins
>   // MIT License
>   // ===================================================================

You may find more infos at the source of this file: https://github.com/thingsym/flexbox-grid-mixins

There's a documentation and some examples but after cloning that repo, I can't find a single diff... oh there it is. Screenshot below.

`skeleton`: each column/block has an horizontal margin shared between left and right (see that lightblue outside of the grid both on left and right? Margin of columns).
It's `.grid > .grid__col-5 { margin: 0 1% 2% }` for example
The gutter is made of the right margin of the column on the left + the left margin of the column on the right.

`margin-offset`: each column/block has a right margin and no left margin. Last child has no right margin.
Example: `.grid-margin-offset > .grid__col-5 { margin-right: 2% }` (and margin-bottom: 2% and override for the :last-child)
The gutter is entirely made of the right margin of the column on the left.

Flex-basis is different because in the first place, the container has different widths (that lightblue outside *skeleton*)... and it's the reason of that mixin

[image: grid by thingsym - examples showing skeleton vs margin-offset parameter]

Comment: You know Stack Overflow has a built in image-hosting service, right? There's no need to go find a 3rd party image-hosting site to post an image.

Comment: @TylerH Nope, didn't try to upload one for years I guess so I didn't see this _new_ :p feature. :) Thanks, I'll edit tomorrow

Comment: @TylerH Thanks a ton .. will go though it on the weekend and accept , please give me some time ... ONCE AGAIN .... THANKS ALOOOOT ! :)